# Auto-refresh keys in a distributed cache to avoid TTL eviction

Tags: java, memcached, distributed-caching

**TLDR**: **Is there a way to periodically refresh keys in Memcached so that those keys are always hot (to minimize cache misses).**

**Longer version**:
I'm using Memcached as a distributed cache. I'm storing big values in the cache (~1MB size of each entry).

My application needs consistent read latencies, but the access pattern of the keys vary greatly. Some keys are accessed every second, while others sometimes aren't accessed for hours.

I want my application to have no cache misses and want all the cache entries to be always hot. Since my access pattern isn't consistent, **I'm wondering if there's a way to periodically refresh the cache?** Any ideas about how this can be achieved?

PS: In a standard setup, the application would put the data in Memcached and then Memcached might evict it after the TTL. It can sometimes evict it sooner if its slab class is full and it can't assign any free pages. However, for this discussion, I'm assuming that TTL is the only mechanism for eviction. And I want to refresh the cache entry and update it's TTL before it can be evicted.